# Call webservice from Android using KSoap simply returning "error" string

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I'm trying to use ksoap to call a simple webservice.  I followed [this video](http://www.vimeo.com/9633556) to try to get started.  When I call "getResponse()" on the envelope I just get the string "Error".  There's no exceptions thrown or any other detail.  I've successfully connected to a simple webservice I just setup on my local machine.  Could this potentially be related to being behind a proxy server here at work?  My code is below:

```
String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
String URL = "http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("Celsius");
pi.setValue("32");
request.addProperty(pi);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try
{
    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a '/' after the namespace.  Took me way too long to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You should write namespace like this.

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org"/;
```